# Equivalent propositions to axiom of replacement in ZC set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have seen a list of propositions that are equivalent to the axiom of choice. I'd like to know this kind of list for the Axiom of replacement as well. I have read that the *Principle of Transfinite Recursion* is one of those propositions. Isn't the existence of set $\{x_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ or $\{x_i: i\in P^n(\mathbb{N})\}$  or for $A\subseteq P^n(\mathbb{N})$, $\{x_i: i\in  A\}$ is equivalent to the axiom of replacement?

Comment: Bear in mind replacement is an axiom *schema*; it's actually infinitely many first-order axioms, which you can only think of as one statement when you go to second-order, which ZFC doesn't do. Since ZFC isn't finitely axiomatizable, but only has one schema, namely replacement (we don't need comprehension separately, but it's often mentioned because of its role in Zermelo set theory, which lacks replacement), any equivalent version of replacement will still include a schema.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you. Then, proposition "For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $A\subseteq P^n(\mathbb{N})$, set  $\{x_i: i\in  A\}$ exists." is a schema? And is it equivalent to the axiom of replacement?

Comment: No, that is a single sentence. Unless you explain what is $x_i$.

Comment: @amoongae I suppose each $x$ gives a separate $\forall n\in\Bbb N\forall A\subseteq P^n(\Bbb N)\exists S\forall y(y\in S\iff\exists i\in A(y=x_i))$ axiom, unless we can quantify over the $x$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Ah, then "For every set $x_i$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}, A\subseteq P^n(\mathbb{N})$ set $\{x_i: i\in  A\}$ exists." is a schema? And is it equivalent to the axiom of replacement? In fact, I'm not sure what the schema is...

Comment: @J.G. As I understand it, because we are using FOL, can't we quantify that $x_i$ are runs over all sets. Is it right that I understand?

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not quite a statement either. Unless the number of the $x_i$ is finite (and fixed) anyway, in which case Replacement plays no role in this anyway. You probably want to say that for every $\varphi(x,y,p)$ and every $p$, if for every $i\in A$ there is exactly one $x$ such that $\varphi(x,i,p)$ holds, then $\{x\mid\varphi(x,i,p), i\in A\}$ is a set. This is just Replacement again with restriction on the domain of the functions. Of course this is not equivalent to Replacement, as my answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\kappa=\beth_\omega$, where $\beth_\omega$ is the cardinal of $\bigcup\{\mathcal P^n(\Bbb N)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Then $V_{\kappa^+}$ is a model of $\sf ZC$ where Replacement fails, since $V_{\kappa+2}$ is already greater than $\kappa^+$ (and therefore there is no von Neumann ordinal in bijection with it). Nevertheless, if $A$ is any set of size at most $\kappa$, then any function whose range is a subset of $V_{\kappa^+}$ is bounded in rank and therefore in the model.

---

On the positive side, the Reflection Principle is equivalent to Replacement. Namely, if $\varphi$ is any formula which holds in $V$, then there is a closed and unbounded class of ordinals $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models\varphi^{V_\alpha}$.

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your answer. Can you give me the definition of $\kappa^+, \kappa+2 $ and $V_\kappa$?

Comment: $\kappa^+$ is the successor cardinal of $\kappa$, whereas $\kappa+2$ is the double-successor *ordinal* of $\kappa$. $V_\alpha$ is the set of those sets whose von Neumann rank is less than $\alpha$.